# How to index a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, indexing

If I have a list of dictionaries in a python script, that I intend to later on `dump` in a `JSON` file as an array of objects, how can I index the keys of a specific dictionary within the list?

Example :

```
dict_list = [{"first_dict": "some_value"}, {"second_dict":"some_value"}, {"third_dict": "[element1,element2,element3]"}]
```

My intuitive solution was `dict_list[-1][0]` (to access the first key of the last dictionary in the list for example). This however gave me the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: There seems to be a misplaced `'` and `}` in your example.

Comment: While your code is not valid python, I suppose you're trying to access a key of a dictionary by its index?

Answer (score 0):

the key inputted into the dictionary will pick the some value in the format dict = {0:some_value}

to find a specific value:

```
list_dictionary = [{"dict1":'value1'},{"dict2","value2"}]
value1 = list_dictionary[0]["dict1"]
```

the 'key' is what you have to use to find a value from a dictionary

Example:

```
dictionary = {0:value}
dictionary[0]
```

in this case it will work

but to pick the elements we will do

```
values = []

for dictionary in dict_list:
   for element in dictionary:
      values.append(dictionary[element])
```

Output:

```
['some_value', 'some_value', ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_list = [{"first_dict": "some_value"}, {"second_dict":"some_value"}, {"third_dict": ['element1','element2','element3']}]
```

If your dict look like this you can do as well

```
dict_list[-1]["third_dict"]
```

You can't access 'the first key' with a int since you have a dict
You can get the first key with `.keys()` and then

```
dict_list[-1].keys()[0]
```

Comment: your first solution `dict_list[-1]["third_dict"]` gave me the error: KeyError: 'third_dict'. This is following the example though, here's the actual list I am testing on: `individual_window_array = [{"window_numeric_name/driver_object_name":f'{window_numeric_name}'}, {"window_description":f'{current_window_description}'}
                                       ,{"window_tabs":f'{current_window_tabs}', "window_custom_title":f'{current_window_title}'}]`

Comment: try dict_list[-1][name of your first key] (in your case window_tabs)

Comment: Sorry there was a type in my comment, it's `[{"window_numeric_name/driver_object_name":f'{window_numeric_name}'}, {"window_description":f'{current_window_description}'}
                                       ,{"window_tabs":f'{current_window_tabs}'}, {"window_custom_title":f'{current_window_title}'}]`. Do you mean try with `"window_custom_title"`?

Comment: Yes, as well you should do the second option if it can change in the futur

Comment: second option gives: `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: it does in this case (and not in mine in my answer) because you have only 1 key.
`.keys()` return all the keys in a object iterable but not indexable. You can do tho `list(dict_list[-1].keys()` but it start to be ugly. I don't know if it have a specific case if you only have one key

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = [{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}, {"key10":"val10"}]
```

Then to access the last dictionary you'd indeed use `dict_list[-1]` but this returns a dictionary with is indexed using its keys and not numbers: `dict_list[0]["key1"]`

To only use numbers, you'd need to get a list of the keys first: `list(dict_list[-1])`. The first element of this list `list(dict_list[-1])[0]` would then be the first key `"key10"`

You can then use indices to access the first key of the last dictionary:

```
dict_index = -1
key_index = 0

d = dict_list[dict_index]
keys = list(d)
val = d[keys[key_index]]
```

However you'd be using the dictionary as a list, so maybe a list of lists would be better suited than a list of dictionaries.

Comment: The first suggestion : `list(dict_list[-1])[0]` gave me the following error when I tried to contain the output in a variable: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` I am not sure what that means. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code section, check if you're storing the extracted value in a similar way. But your error rather sounds like you're passing the extracted value to a function that expects a dictionary instead, so I think the issue lies in the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

By using **dict_list[-1][0]**, you are trying to access a list with a list, which you do not have. You have a list with a dict key within a list.

Taking your example **dict_list[-1][0]**:

- When you mention **dict_list** you are already "in the list".
- The first index [-1] is referring to the last item of the list.
- The second index would only be "usable" if the item mentioned in the previous index were a list. Hence the error.

Using:

```
dict_list=[{"first_dict": "some_value"}, {"second_dict":"some_value"},{"third_dict": [0,1,2]}]
```

to access the **value** of **third_dict** you need:

```
for value in list(dict_list[-1].values())[0]:
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of dictionary keys and you are using one of the latest python versions (key stays in same order), so:

```py
dict_list = [
    {"first_dict": "some_value"}
    , {"second_dict":"some_value"}
    , {"third_dict": ["element1", "element2", "element3"]}
]

first_key = next(iter(dict_list[-1].keys()))

### OR: value

first_value = next(iter(dict_list[-1].values()))

### OR: both key and value

first_key, first_value = next(iter(dict_list[-1].items()))


print(first_key)
print(first_key, first_value)
print(first_value)
```

Comment: using this gives me the error : `Convert a String to Variable Name in Python` when I run it through this method: `locals().update(first_value)` . Any idea what this means? Thanks.

Comment: @double_wizz it is not a dictionary you cannot update it as dictionary